# Properties of Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I just want to check if my understanding of linear maps is correct on these notions.

Firstly suppose $f : V \to W$ is a linear map between vector spaces, with $\dim(V) = n$ and $\dim(W) = m$

Suppose $m > n$, then clearly $\text{rank}(f) \neq m$ (this is impossible), so suppose $\text{rank}(f) \leq n$, then $\text{Im}[f]$ is a $\text{rank}(f)$-dimensional subspace of $W$, and it is not surjectiive/onto since $\text{Im}[f] \neq W$

If $\text{rank}(f) = n$, then it is injective, but if $\text{rank}(f) < n$, then it is neither injective nor surjective. (a proof follows a similar argument as detailed below)

Suppose now that $m < n$, and suppose $\text{rank}(f) = m$ (it's impossible for  $\text{rank}(f) > m$), then $\text{Im}[f]$ is an $m$-dimensional subpsace of $W$ and is surjective, but not injective. To see why this is true pick $\alpha = (x_1, x_2, ...., x_m, x_{m+1}, ... x_n)$ and $\beta = (y_1, y_2, ...., y_m, y_{m+1}, ... y_n) \in V$ , where $x_i = y_i$ for $i \leq m$ and $x_i \neq y_i$ for $i > m$, then $A\alpha = A\beta$ (which is a $m \times 1$ matrix).

If $\text{rank}(f) < m$, then $f$ is neither surjective nor injective.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: What is $dim(V)$ and $dim(W)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted only one error: at the third paragraph, you wrote that $\operatorname{Im}f$ is a $n$-dimensionl subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. No; it is a $\operatorname{rank}(f)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah sorry about that was just a typo I forgot to fix after editing the case for $\leq n$, I've since updated the the question

Comment: I've updated the question again